# Best method to increase PHP memory limit?

Tags: php, wordpress

This is the error log I get when trying to access some pages on my website, it's very rare but happens occasionally.

> [18-Jan-2017 16:10:35 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 3145728) (tried to allocate 30720 bytes)

How do I increase this? My WP Memory Limit is already 512mb.

Comment: Is this on your server, or a hosted server

Comment: Have you tried editing `php.ini` `memory_limit`?  Or `ini_set('memory_limit', '12M');`? Or `php_value memory_limit 512M`in `.htaccess` file? Usually this kind of error means that you have a issue in your scripts, and allocating more memory will not solve this.

Comment: Are you sure you can not optimize code to use less memory. 512M Is a lot. I was doing image processing on VM with that memory size total (PHP was @ 128).

Comment: This a wordpress website hosted online through godaddy. There are 900+ image files on the website.

Comment: Unless my calculator is bust (or my brain) `3145728` is 3 meg. Do you really only have 3 meg allocated as PHP's `memory_limit` Sounds really fishy to me

Comment: Currently the PHP Memory_Limit says: undefined MB

Comment: Where does it say that?

Comment: The theme I have says the (System Status): http://image.prntscr.com/image/02e3c6f692764f57b444cfc9de8496a5.png

Comment: If this is an issue within my scripts how I would I solve this?

Comment: if you exhaust 512mb, the solution is to fix the loops that are using so much memory, not get it even higher.

Comment: Is there a way to figure out what things are using so much memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the terminal try `which php`
find where php.ini is located.
Edit php.ini, increase memory_limit value.
Restart apache/fpm et al.

Should do the trick for you. The better question is, why do are you wanting to increase the limit?

Comment: Sometimes when I click on certain pages, I get a 500 Internal Server Error and the error log shows.

**[18-Jan-2017 16:10:35 UTC] PHP Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 3145728) (tried to allocate 30720 bytes)**

Comment: That is ~3MBs, I would say upping the limit is applicable. Remember the memery_limit is PER PHP process. So if if you have 10 requests at the same time that is 30Mb at the current setting. Set to 16MBs, would be 160Mb total for 10 requests at the same time.

Comment: @Zecele if this solves your issue please mark the question as correct.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the PHP.ini and haven't seen the error since, though my server memory limit still says: undefined MB

Comment: @Zecele What was the value you assigned to `memory_limit`?

Comment: memory_limit = 512M;